# How to Close automatically the web page if the user no responde?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello Team I need your help with a validation

I need to close my web page automatically if the user no responde yes or not after 30 minutes.

```
constructor(private loginService:AuthenticationService,private router: Router) {
          this.setTimeout();
          this.userInactive.subscribe(()=> this.cancel());
      }

      setTimeout() {
        this.userActivity = setTimeout(() => this.userInactive.next(undefined), 300000);
      }

      @HostListener('window:mousemove') refreshUserState() {
        clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
        this.setTimeout();
      }

      cancel() {
        var cancel = confirm("We Detected Inactivity Do you want to continue?");
        if (cancel) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/logout']);
          return false;
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Try using localstorage***

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
const MINUTES_UNITL_AUTO_LOGOUT = 60 // in mins
const CHECK_INTERVAL = 15000 // in ms
const STORE_KEY =  'lastAction';
@Injectable()
export class AutoLogoutService {
 public getLastAction() {
    return parseInt(localStorage.getItem(STORE_KEY));
  }
 public setLastAction(lastAction: number) {
    localStorage.setItem(STORE_KEY, lastAction.toString());
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.check();
    this.initListener();
    this.initInterval();
    localStorage.setItem(STORE_KEY,Date.now().toString());
  }

  initListener() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', () => this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',()=> this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseout',() => this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown',() => this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup',() => this.reset());
    document.body.addEventListener('keypress',() => this.reset());
  }

  reset() {
    this.setLastAction(Date.now());
  }

  initInterval() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.check();
    }, CHECK_INTERVAL);
  }

  check() {
    const now = Date.now();
    const timeleft = this.getLastAction() + MINUTES_UNITL_AUTO_LOGOUT * 60 * 1000;
    const diff = timeleft - now;
    const isTimeout = diff < 0;

    if (isTimeout)  {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.router.navigate(['./login']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cancel method....you need to again set the timeout...

```
  cancel() {
    var cancel = confirm("We Detected Inactivity Do you want to continue?");
    if (cancel) {
      clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
      this.setTimeout();
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/logout']);
      return false;
    }
```